# Postgres query works on console but using it as a scope in a view renders syntax errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I'm using a query to fetch the `SubscriptionCart` with the oldest `authorized_at` date from a `Subscription`.

Since a `Subscription` `has_many` `SubscriptionCart`, I filter the carts with the same `plan_id` as the Subscription `plan_id`. I also use `WHERE` statements for the `Subscription` and `SubscriptionCart` statuses as well.

The query seems to work fine on console, but when I put it in a Subscription scope and try to use it in my views I get:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 6: ...ubscriptions.id, subscription_carts.authorized_at WHERE "sub...
```

What is going on?

query:

```
select distinct on (s.id) s.id, sc.authorized_at as cart_authorized_at, s.*
from subscriptions s
join subscription_carts sc on sc.subscription_id = s.id and sc.plan_id = s.plan_id
where sc.status = 'processed'
and s.status IN ('authorized','in_trial', 'paused')
order by s.id, sc.authorized_at
```

scope:

```
  scope :with_current_price_version, -> {
    select("
      DISTINCT ON (subscriptions.id) subscriptions.id,
      subscription_carts.authorized_at as version_cart_authorized_at,
      subscriptions.*
    ")
    .joins("
      INNER JOIN subscription_carts
      ON subscription_carts.subscription_id = subscriptions.id                 
      AND subscription_carts.plan_id = subscriptions.plan_id   
      WHERE subscription_carts.status = 'processed'
      AND subscriptions.status IN ('authorized','in_trial', 'paused')
      ORDER BY subscriptions.id, subscription_carts.authorized_at
    ")
  }
```

EDIT: Moving the WHERE, AND & ORDER BY clauses outside of the .join fixed the issue.

updated scope looks like:

```
  scope :with_current_price_version, -> {
    select("DISTINCT ON (subscriptions.id) subscriptions.id,
           subscription_carts.authorized_at as version_cart_authorized_at, subscriptions.*")
      .joins("INNER JOIN subscription_carts on subscription_carts.subscription_id = subscriptions.id
             AND subscription_carts.plan_id = subscriptions.plan_id")
      .where("subscription_carts.status = 'processed'
             AND subscriptions.status IN ('authorized','in_trial', 'paused')")
      .order("subscriptions.id, subscription_carts.authorized_at")
  }
```

Comment: You can try moving the `WHERE`, `AND` and `ORDER BY` parts in the `joins` method outside of it. It might not make it work, but you're adding the whole query within the `joins` method, which looks confusing at first sight.

Comment: Nice, I was just trying to replicate your problem in local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  def self.with_latest_subscription_cart
    s = arel_table
    sc = SubscriptionCart.arel_table.alias('sc')
    select(
      'DISTINCT ON(subscriptions.id)',
      :id, # not sure why you want to select this explicitly 
      s[Arel.star],
      sc[:authorized_at]
    )
    .joins(
      s.join(sc).on(
        sc[:subscription_id].eq(s[:id]).and(
          sc[:plan_id].eq(s[:plan_id])
        )
      ).join_sources
    )
    .where(
      status: 'processed',
      sc: {
        status: ['authorized','in_trial', 'paused']
      }
    )
    .order(:id, sc[:authorized_at])
  end
end
```

It would be a lot easier though if you moved `subscription_carts.plan_id = subscriptions.plan_id` into the `WHERE` clause instead so that you can just use `joins(:subscription_carts)`.

Comment: Thank you Max. Is there any way to order by the authorized_at date instead of by subscription.id? I'm getting an error related to the distinct on and order by expressions being different.

Comment: I would probably use a lateral join - see my answer to your other question.